# Reapply for an Irish Visa 1 year after refusal

Tags: visa-refusals, online-resources, ireland, applications

I applied for an Irish visa a year ago. This was refused due to insufficient funds. We dropped the plan of travel then and did not make any appeal. Now when I try to apply and book an appointment I get the error message “the passport number is duplicate” and I am unable to make the payment or book an appointment.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Contact the online visa applications system (AVATS) helpline 
http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/contact-visas

Describe your problem in detail and provide the following information:
- Visa Application/Transaction Number assigned to your application
- Full name on the application
- Date of birth
- Nationality
- Passport number